# What is the correct way to add or override "type" in filebeat.yml?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, filebeat, elk

I am working on stashing jenkins logs using filbeat to ELK stack. I need to add or override "type" in filbeat.yml.

Please find here the logstash.conf
[logstash.conf.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfZKe.jpg)

I need to add or override the "type" (highlighted in red in picture) in my filebeat.yml.

Please find the filebeat.yml here:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
   - /opt/app/elk/logs/jenkins.log 
  multiline.pattern: '^%{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY}, %{YEAR} %{TIME} (AM|PM)'
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: before
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a field using filebeat uses the following [configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html):

```
- type: log 
  paths:
    - /path/to/your/files/*.log
  fields:
    type: your-type
  fields_under_root: true
```

The `fields_under_root: true` will add the field `type` in the top-level of the document, if you set it to false, it will add inside the `fields` object, so you have a field named `fields.type`.

Comment: Hi lean,
Thank you for your quick response. I will try the solution and will reach out to you here, if i am unable to do the same.